# How to prevent XMLReader from unescaping characters

Tags: c#, escaping, xmlreader

I'd like to create a simple XMLreader which reads a complete node (including subnodes) as text:

```
string TXML = @"<xml><text>hall&#xF6;le</text></xml>";

XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(TXML));
r.Read(); r.Read();

string o = r.ReadOuterXml();
```

`ReadOuterXml` does the job but it unescapes the already escaped signs:

```
"<text>hallöle</text>"
```

I whish to have the result:

```
"<text>hall&#xF6;le</text>"
```

How can I ommit that 'unescaping'. I want to store this fragments to a db and do need that escaping. Furthermore I dont want to parse and recreate the fragments.

Comment: Can you alter the XML source to escape the `&` symbol with `&amp;`?

Comment: When you insert the data into the database, I would think you'd want it to be the correct data, not the escaped data.  That way you can search for it and when you read the data back from the database it will be correct.  You shouldn't need to escape the data when you are inserting it into the database if you are using ADO and parameters.

Comment: I am the man in the middle. I can not alter the source. Furthermore if I deliver the stored data back to the client he expects it escaped again. That's why i'd like to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, I wanted to keep the escaped characters when reading from xml, but in may case when calling ReadOuterXml(), only some of characters were kept and at least oane was transformed (I had " instead of &quot;)

My solution was the following:

```
string TXML = @"<xml><text>hall&#xF6;le</text></xml>";
TXML = TXML.Replace("&", "&amp;");
XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(TXML));
r.Read(); r.Read();
// now we are at the text element
r.ReadStartElement()
var content = SecurityElement.Escape(r.ReadContentAsString())
r.ReadEndElement()
```

Answer (score 2):

I found two solutions. Both not very nice, but maybe you can tell me which has less drawbacks.

Both solutions rely on direcly using the ´XmlTextReader´ instead of ´XmlReader´. It comes with the property ´LinePosition' which lead me to the first solution and with the method ´ReadChars´ as basis for the second one.

### Solution (1), get data from original string via indices

Problems:

- doesn't work on stream inputs
- doesn't work if xml has several lines

Code

```
string TXML = @"<xml><data></data><rawnode at=""10 4""><text>hall&#xF6;le</text><z d=""2"">3</z></rawnode><data></data></xml>";

//XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(TXML));
XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(TXML));

// read to node which shall be retrived "raw"
while ( r.Read() )
{
    if ( r.Name.Equals("rawnode") )
        break;
}

// here we start
int Begin = r.LinePosition;
r.Skip();
int End = r.LinePosition;

// get it out
string output=TXML.Substring(Begin - 2, End - Begin);
```

### Solution (2), get data with ´ReadChars´

Problems:

- I have to parse and recreate the 'outer' markup of my tag which I'd like to read.
- This might cost performance.
- I might introduce errors.

Code:

```
// ... again create XmlTextReader and read to rawnode, then:
// here we start
int buflen = 15;
char[] buf = new char[buflen];
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder("<",20);

//get start tag and attributes    
string tagname=r.Name;
sb.Append(tagname);
bool hasAttributes = r.MoveToFirstAttribute();
while (hasAttributes)
{
    sb.Append(" " + r.Name + @"=""" + r.Value + @"""");
    hasAttributes = r.MoveToNextAttribute();
}
sb.Append(@">");
r.MoveToContent();

//get raw inner data    
int cnt;
while ((cnt = r.ReadChars(buf, 0, buflen)) > 0)
{
    if ( cnt<buflen )
        buf[cnt]=(char)0;
    sb.Append(buf);
}

//append end tag    
sb.Append("</" + tagname + ">");

// get it out
string output = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on you xml header and verify that it contains something like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>`

For escaping and unescaping you could use the c# functions `InnerXml` and `InnerText` :

```
public static string XmlEscape(string unescaped)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    var node = doc.CreateElement("root");
    node.InnerText = unescaped;
    return node.InnerXml;
}

public static string XmlUnescape(string escaped)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    var node = doc.CreateElement("root");
    node.InnerXml = escaped;
    return node.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: ´string TXML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-9""?><xml><text>hall&#xF6;le</text></xml>";´ but parsing that string with the same code didn't change the result.

Comment: Furthermore thanks for your mehtods Xml(un)Escape but using them would mean to read and recreate the whole inner XML. That is exactly what I try to ommit.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your desire to not have to parse and recreate the escaped characters, but I can't find a way not to unless you go full on customized with it. Perhaps this isn't so bad?

```
string TXML = @"<xml><text>hall&#xF6;le</text></xml>";
TXML = TXML.Replace("&", "&amp;");
XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(TXML));
r.Read(); r.Read();

string o = r.ReadOuterXml();
o = o.Replace("&amp;", "&");
```

Comment: Yes, maybe this is the only way. Thanks for that. But appart from having a very rough solution it might be visible in application performance. I read the fragments out of a big XML and would have to read and write the source several times.

Comment: The same source? Just read it in once and store it in a variable that you can then use to write out as many times as you need.